# How is input parsed in C?

Tags: c, parsing, input, buffer

**Full, adjusted, code at end of post**

If I were to ask the user for input and grab the it with, say, scanf(), how does this process work (specifics regarding buffers and the like) ?

What is meant when people make references to 'flush' the buffer? I have also heard that it is bad practice to flush the input (or, rather, undefined ?), but flushing the output stream is what functions like fflush() were created for.
-- What is mean by 'stream' in the context above?

So, procedurally, if I were to ask for input like:

```
printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", string);
```

What happens to the input; where does the string go to be 'grabbed' by the scanf function?

What does 'whitespace' appear as in input buffers? (a space character, NULL, etc?)

---

In my mind, although literature I've read has never specifically addressed these questions, I imagine the input from the user, or from a FILE, to be stored in some temporary char array that is accessed by, and printed/stored using the appropriate pointers.

The reason I bring this up is because I have a relevant problem with the following code:

```
int main(){
    char string[20];
    char string2[20];

//strlen test
    printf("Enter a string: ");
        scanf("%s", string);
    printf("\t length: %d\n", strlen(string));

//strcat test
    printf("Enter two strings to concatentate: ");
        scanf("%s %s", string, string2);
    strcat(string2, string);
    printf("\nConcatenated: %s\n\n\n", string);

return 0;
```

}

**AS AN ASIDE: the strlen() and strcat() functions above were defined locally, so the arguments may not match what you are familiar with from the C libraries.**

Produces the following output:

[image: img]

I assumed, that once the scanf function encounters whitespace it assumes the end of the string. Although, the remaining input still exists in the buffer. Then, when I ask for more input, the entered data is placed at the end of the buffer. So, when scanf() is called this time, the 'andothernonsensehere' is taken as the next input since it exists earlier in the buffer.

*Although, if what I stated above is true, shouldn't the second 'andothernonsensehere' string and the first string entered at the second call, 'sherrell,' be concatenated?*

---

tl;dr verison
How do I flush the buffer to ensure the next event of input will be captured by scanf() ?

---

**Full, edited, code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char string[20];
    char string2[20];

//strlen test
    printf("Enter a string: ");
        scanf("%s", string);
    printf("\t length: %d\n", strlen(string));
    clear(); //make sure buffer is empty

//strcat test
    printf("Enter two strings to concatentate: ");
        scanf("%s %s", string, string2);

    strcat(string2, string);
    printf("\nConcatenated: %s\n\n\n", string);

    return 0;
}

void strcat(char *toCopy, char *org){
    while(*org != NULL) org++; //find end of characters
    while( (*org++ = *toCopy++) != NULL); //copy
}

int strlen(char *a){
    char *b = a;
    while(*b++ != NULL);
    return b-a;
}


void clear(){
    while(getchar() != '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically got it right, although the buffering may not be where you think it is.

`scanf` does not maintain a buffer. Conceptually, it reads one character at a time until the format or the input is exhausted.

However, terminal input is normally buffered *by the terminal driver*. Or, to be more accurate, if there are no characters waiting to be read, a request for terminal input does not return anything until the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed, even if the program is only reading one character. Unread characters are retained in the kernel, where they will be provided to the user program as requested. (The terminal driver also handles echoing the characters as they are typed, and handling backspaces, and many other things.) All of this behaviour can be changed, though. See `man stty` and `man termios` (and possibly `man tty_ioctl`) for lots of details. Lots.

So `scanf` is completely unaware of what is to come. It just consumes characters until it's satisfied, and, if necessary, calls `ungetc` to return the last character it read but didn't need.

Now, your question:

> *shouldn't the second 'andothernonsensehere' string and the first string entered at the second call, 'sherrell,' be concatenated?*

Answer: yes, they should. And they will be with the standard library function `strcat`, provided you put its arguments in the right order and make sure that `string` has enough space to hold the concatenation plus the terminating `NUL` character.

As you say, I cannot make any assumptions about your `strcat`, so I don't know that it takes  its arguments in the same order as the standard library version. However, if it does then the behaviour you see is to be expected: `strcat` will append `string` to the end of `string2` (overwriting random memory, because `string2` isn't big enough to hold the concatenation), but that doesn't change `string` (unless `string` is the random memory being overwritten). So when you print out `string`, you see what it was originally, i.e. a 20 character string whose terminating `NUL` byte was also overwritten over some other random memory location.

With all that undefined behaviour going on, your program could have produced virtually any output or it could have segfaulted or triggered [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). I think your C compiler is probably aligning strings on double-word boundaries, because I would have expected `string2` to immediately follow `string`, so that the trailing `NUL` after you put 20 characters into `string` would be the first byte of `string2`, which would then be overwritten when `scanf` fills in `string2`. The consequences of appending `string` to `string2` at that point would be, umm, interesting.

Comment: Thank you. The concept makes more sense now. I added to the end of the OP the full code, including my version of strcat(). Any suggestions?

Comment: @sherrellbc: My suggestions: use `-Wall` (at least), and make `string` and `string2` bigger (or use shorter inputs). I modified your code by: changing NULL to 0 (NULL is a pointer); putting strlen, strcat and clear at the beginning, and changing their names to avoid collision with gcc builtin; and changing both buffers to 40 characters. It worked fine. (gcc still warned correctly about ignoring the return value of scanf. You should always check scanf's return value.)

Comment: Is function placement a matter of concern? (i.e. before/after main). I always program in such a way that I include function prototypes (albeit not here) out of habit. I am aware that if you have a function that calls another function which is defined below itself then the calling function will not 'see' the defined function and the program will not compile. I was surprised to see that the code I wrote compiled because of the lack of function prototypes and the fact that main was calling functions defined after its own definition.

Comment: Also, the code I posted at the end of the OP works after I have added such functionality as the clear() function which removes any excess input in the buffer. My comment about your suggestions were directed to you concerns about how my implementation of strcat() compared to the libraries version.

Comment: @sherrellbc: ah. Aside from the use of NULL where you mean 0, I don't think it's a problem for short strings. It suffers from precisely the same insecurity as the builtin does. The builtin can probably blitz memory faster, since it will use vector operations and double-word read/write and whatever other tricks they come up with. Really, the biggest problem is buffer overruns. I'd suggest you implement strncat instead of strcat, and that you put the arguments in the same order (otherwise, it's really confusing to the reader). But see http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

```
    String2
```

is undeclared, which the input is "" empty string. So you input the first and concatenated with an empty string produce the same string as the original input
%s is the 'input' where s stand for string and you store it inside of string. Which is where you get the inputs from.

Comment: I did not post the entire code. This is an example where the problem I list above would be evident.

Comment: This answer is not relevant to my question at all. I know how the scanf() functions works.

Comment: scanf("%s %s", string, string2);
This line is where it gives you the problem

Comment: What is the problem? I attributed my problems with this line: **scanf("%s", string);** because, given the input I showed in the image above, there are essentially two string separated by whitespace present in the input. The input, until the whitespace is encountered, is stored in the string. When the second scanf() is called, **scanf("%s %s", string, string2)**, the input buffer's next available string of characters(before the next whitespace or escape character, is the 'andothernonsensehere' string shown in the image. Thus, explaining why it is printed. If I am wrong, please explain.

Comment: try this
`scanf("%s %s", string, string2);`
`strcat(string2, " ");`
`strcat(string2, string);`